# "In-source builds are not allowed" in cmake

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake

I'm new to cmake, and I'm only using it to install opencv on my ubuntu linux.
Here's the command I ran: `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/jinha/OCV/source`

Then it returns the error:

```
FATAL: In-source builds are not allowed. You should create separate directory for build files.
```

My current directory, `~/OCV/build/opencv`, does contain the CMakefiles.txt file, so that's not the problem. I tried to change the directory in my command, but they all raise the same error. I saw the other answers on this issue, so I erased `CMakeFiles` directory and `CMakeCache.txt` file every time before I ran the command, but none of them worked.
Thanks.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

It wants you to create a separate build directory (anywhere), and run cmake there.  For example:

```
mkdir my_build_dir
cd my_build_dir
rm ../CMakeCache.txt
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/jinha/OCV/source
```

Note the `..` in this example telling cmake where to look for the source.

**In case you didn't remove `CMakeCache.txt` before building again, it will still show this error.**
So, please remember to delete `CMakeCache.txt` first before running `cmake`.

Comment: CMAKE is just being smart and preserving your sources as "*pristine*" by requiring you build in another directory to prevent dirtying your source with object and other build files...

Comment: The source directory "/Users/user/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: This solution did not work for me and I am not sure what CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX should point to. Is that the full path there the sources are located?

Comment: Everybody comes here after trying to install opencv, then following *its instructions* and it still says that pesky error message, until you delete that file.  Thanks for the tip and saving me time... :)

Comment: Thanks again for noting to remove `CMakeCache.txt`; installation does not work otherwise.

Comment: Why can't cmake tell me about the cache file?

Comment: @Nick: CMake is an open source project; if you want to improve its error messages, you can.  https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake

Comment: Also note that if you ever used `cmake` in the source directory, it will fail with the same message again and again. You will need to delete the generated build or reclone the sources.

Comment: Remember to do "make", "make install", and "make clean" after this.

Comment: So, if I change one file in a massive project and I just want to recompile it and its dependecies, is this the way to do it? Or will this cause the whole thing to have to recompile?

Answer (score 14):

After you have success downloaded and unzipped OpenCV sources from [sources](https://opencv.org/releases.html) you need create simple command-file install.sh. For example, your working dir will be /home/user/myopencv

So /home/user/myopencv/install.sh will be contain next code:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm CMakeCache.txt
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
make
make install
make clean
```

Next

```
chmod 777 install.sh
./install.sh
```

And after the all you will get those executable files:

```
root@cartman:/usr/local/bin# ls -las | grep opencv
 32 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   29888 апр 20 18:10 opencv_annotation
244 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  247608 апр 20 18:10 opencv_createsamples
244 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  247504 апр 20 18:10 opencv_haartraining
 20 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   18600 апр 20 18:10 opencv_performance
288 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  294592 апр 20 18:10 opencv_traincascade
 16 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   14288 апр 20 18:10 opencv_version
 60 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   61040 апр 20 18:10 opencv_visualisation
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This worked for me up until the "Next" section. I don't see any install.sh

Comment: You must create it yourself.

Comment: It is not mandatory to create `install.sh` but it helps a lot if one wants to avoid typing multiple commands.