# Want to build some necessary Libraries for feature detection. Got some error

Tags: c++, opencv

Want to build some necessary Libraries for feature detection. Got some error.
At first, I tried

`$ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/Desktop/opencv_contrib-master/`

and I got error message

> FATAL: In-source builds are not allowed.
>           You should create a separate directory for build files.

So, I've followed 
["In-source builds are not allowed" in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518317/in-source-builds-are-not-allowed-in-cmake)

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/Desktop/opencv_contrib-master
```

but still got error message

> CMake Error: The source directory "/home/ryucaps/opencv" does not
>   appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. Specify --help for usage, or press
>   the help button on the CMake GUI.

Can't figure out what's going on. I only wanted to import some libraries that i don't have yet on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to compile and install OpenCV with additional module `opencv_contrib-master`, right?

Follow these steps for a relatively clean solution:

- Download both [Opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/3.4.1) and [additional module](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/3.4.1) to the same directory (for example `/home/MyUser/Libs`; note that I gave you the links to the particular OpenCV versions (in this case 3.4.1), not just to master branch
- Go to `/home/MyUser/Libs` and unzip the archives (e.g. `unzip 3.4.1.zip`)
- Go to `/home/MyUser/Libs/opencv-3.4.1` and create the build dir `mkdir build`
- Go to build dir `cd build` and execute `cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/MyUser/Libs/opencv_contrib-3.4.1/modules ..` ; Note the `..` in the end of the command
- Execute `make`
- Execute `sudo make install`