# Building opencv error: In-source builds are not allowed

Tags: android, python, opencv, cmake

I modified opencv recipe in python-for-android as following.

### **init**.py

```
import os
import sh
from pythonforandroid.recipe import NDKRecipe
from pythonforandroid.toolchain import (
current_directory,
shprint,
)
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

class OpenCVRecipe(NDKRecipe):
version = '3.4.1'
url = 'https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/{version}.zip'
#md5sum = '2ddfa98e867e6611254040df841186dc'
depends = ['numpy']
#patches = ['patches/p4a_build-2.4.10.1.patch']
generated_libraries = ['cv2.so']

def prebuild_arch(self, arch):
    self.apply_patches(arch)

def get_recipe_env(self, arch):
    env = super(OpenCVRecipe, self).get_recipe_env(arch)
    env['PYTHON_ROOT'] = self.ctx.get_python_install_dir()
    env['ANDROID_NDK'] = self.ctx.ndk_dir
    env['ANDROID_SDK'] = self.ctx.sdk_dir
    env['SITEPACKAGES_PATH'] = self.ctx.get_site_packages_dir()
    return env

def build_arch(self, arch):
    with current_directory(self.get_build_dir(arch.arch)):
        env = self.get_recipe_env(arch)
        cvsrc = self.get_build_dir(arch.arch)
        lib_dir = os.path.join(self.ctx.get_python_install_dir(), "lib")

        shprint(sh.cmake,
                '-DP4A=ON', '-DANDROID_ABI={}'.format(arch.arch),
                '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE={}/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake'.format(cvsrc),
                '-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH={}/include/python3.6'.format(env['PYTHON_ROOT']),
                '-DPYTHON_LIBRARY={}/lib/libpython3.6.so'.format(env['PYTHON_ROOT']),
                '-DPYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR={}/numpy/core/include'.format(env['SITEPACKAGES_PATH']),
                '-DANDROID_EXECUTABLE={}/tools/android'.format(env['ANDROID_SDK']),
                '-DBUILD_TESTS=OFF', '-DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF',
                '-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF', '-DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF',
                '-DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH={}'.format(env['SITEPACKAGES_PATH']),
                cvsrc,
                _env=env)
        shprint(sh.make, '-j', str(cpu_count()), 'opencv_python')
        shprint(sh.cmake, '-DCOMPONENT=python', '-P', './cmake_install.cmake')
        sh.cp('-a', sh.glob('./lib/{}/lib*.so'.format(arch.arch)), lib_dir)

recipe = OpenCVRecipe()
```

---

I got error while python-for-android build opencv.

> sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
>
> RAN: /usr/local/bin/cmake -DP4A=ON -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
>   -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/ubuntu/build/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/opencv/armeabi-v7a/opencv/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake
>   -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/ubuntu/build/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/simpleapp/include/python3.6
>   -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/ubuntu/build/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/simpleapp/lib/libpython3.6.so
>   -DPYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/ubuntu/build/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/simpleapp/numpy/core/include
>   -DANDROID_EXECUTABLE=/home/ubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/ubuntu/build/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/simpleapp
>   /home/ubuntu/build/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/opencv/armeabi-v7a/opencv
>
> STDOUT: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (message):
>
> FATAL: In-source builds are not allowed.
>
> You should create a separate directory for build files.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

How to fix it?

Comment: Error says that you can't run cmake from the directory with CMakeLists.txt. So first - remove CMakeCache.txt, than create build directory and call cmake from that build directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["In-source builds are not allowed" in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518317/in-source-builds-are-not-allowed-in-cmake)

Comment: @DmitriiZ. I undersatnd about the directory problem. How can I modify my python code to run cmake in other build directory?

Comment: @Tsyvarev It is different. I would like to run cmake programmatically. I would like to fix my python code.

Comment: consider `rm ../CMakeCache.txt` and rerunning. that worked for me