# Using Freetype library with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, freetype, freetype2

I'm trying to set up a C++ project using CMake, and I'd like to use the Freetype library in my project. My CMakeLists currently looks like this, where I have glfw and glad as git submodules that I then let CMake build and link.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(timeless-engine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glfw)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glad)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}" glfw/include glad/include)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glad glfw)
```

I'd love to add Freetype here as another git submodule (by using this mirror for example: https://github.com/Mojang/freetype2) but when I include it the same way, by using `add_subdirectory`, I get the following errors: `In-source builds are not permitted! Make a separate folder for building,`. Would love to get some help with this, I've tried using FindFreetype modules, but not sure how those are supposed to work. Because I'd like to have an easy build process for multiple users, I'd love it if something like the flow I have with git submodules could work, and not have other users of my project be responsible for installing freetype themselves.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How do you call CMake? Can you please provide the commands you run to invoke CMake? Here is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45518317/3987854) with an answer that may help.

Comment: I was just running `cmake .` in the folder. I read the question you linked and when I create a directory, cd into that, and run `cmake ..` it works! I felt like I tried this before and it didn't work. Oh CMake, you're a harsh mistress! Thanks very much for your quick reply!

Comment: A couple notes... you shouldn't give an absolute path to `add_subdirectory`, you should specify PRIVATE in `target_link_libraries`, and the targets should set the include directories for you, so you shouldn't need that line.

Comment: Also consider using `find_package` and asking your users to install your dependencies via vcpkg. If you don't want to do that, then git submodules are fine. If you don't like the hassle of git submodules, then consider the FetchContent module